# how to hide the line when i draw my chart

Tags: highcharts

I have this chart and I made some changes in the code so that only I show the points :

```
 chart: {
           //   type: 'spline',
              zoomType: 'x, y',
              panning: true,
              parKey: 'shift'
          },

          title: {
              text: 'Area de Grafica'
          },
          xAxis: {
              categories: ['']
          },
          yAxis: {
              title:{
                  text: ''


              }
          },
          tooltip:{
            crosshairs: [true,true],

             formatter: function() { 
                return this.x + ', ' + this.y;
              } 
          },
          series: [{
              name: 'grafica tabla de valores',
              data: [[val1, val2], [val3, val4], [val5, val6], [val7, val8], [val9, val10], [val11, val12], [val13, val14], [val15, val16], [val17, val18], [val19, val20]],
              lineWidth: 0, 
              marker: {
                  enabled: true,
                  radius: 5,
                  fillColor: 'Red',
                  symbol: 'url(assets/imgs/sun.png)' //'diamond', 'square',
            //lineWidth: 2,
            //lineColor: 'Black',
            //fillColor: 'white'
        }    
          }],
          states: {
              hover: {
                  lineWidthPlus: 0
              }
          },
          exporting: {
            showTable: true
           },

      });
```

When I run the app it works but at the moment when I move the mouse cursor to the graphic area, you see the line.

I was trying something like 'showLines' but it doesn't work :(

Comment: `states` should be set per series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zdcLp1n8/25/ - not on the chart

Comment: THANK YOU!! it works good C: